# Need to remove Note: from the start of a string using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have been tasked with styling XML and so far nearly all of the tags I have been given are either p or ph which just display the contents of the tag on screen and I can style as required

eg:

```
<p outputclass="LC AStatProv">Council Regulation (EC) No 2201/2003 of 27 November 2003 Concerning Jurisdiction and the Recognition and Enforcement of Judgments in Matrimonial Matters and in Matters of Parental Responsibility, repealing Regulation (EC) No 1347/2000 (Brussels II Revised) (2003) OJ L 338/1, Art&#x00A0;20</p>
```

will display as:

Council Regulation (EC) No 2201/2003 of 27 November 2003 Concerning Jurisdiction and the Recognition and Enforcement of Judgments in Matrimonial Matters and in Matters of Parental Responsibility, repealing Regulation (EC) No 1347/2000 (Brussels II Revised) (2003) OJ L 338/1, Art 20

Today I have noticed that a new **note** tag has been used and this is causing "Note: " to be prepended to the beginning of each string eg:

```
<p outputclass="LC ACourt"><note outputclass="CaseSearchCourt">Court of Appeal</note></p>
```

will display as:

Note: Re A (Abduction: Interim Directions: Accommodation by Local Authority) [2010] EWCA Civ 586 [2011] 1 FLR 1

The FO produced for this is:

```
<fo:block><fo:inline font-weight="bold" border-right-width="0pt" border-left-width="0pt">Note: </fo:inline>  Court of Appeal</fo:block>
```

I have tried the following code gleaned from elsewhere on this site but it didn't remove the string I wanted:

```
<xsl:template match="note">
        <note>
            <xsl:if test="contains(., 'Note:')">
                <xsl:call-template name="remove">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </note>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="remove">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($value, 'Note:'), substring-after($value, 'Note:'))"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

I have tried to see where XSLT gets the "Note: " from but can't find it anywhere so my next thought is to try and pattern match the string and remove "Note: " from the beginning of the string. Is this a good way to go about this and how would I do this?

thanks.

**EDIT: Just to summarise my rambling and confusing question.**

Where it renders:

Note: Re A (Abduction: Interim Directions: Accommodation by Local Authority) [2010] EWCA Civ 586 [2011] 1 FLR 1

I just want it to render:

Re A (Abduction: Interim Directions: Accommodation by Local Authority) [2010] EWCA Civ 586 [2011] 1 FLR 1

**EDIT 2 and the answer**

My initial investigations were based upon grepping for Note: which wasn't being found. I have though found the following:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/note ')]">
```

and then commented out the following lines:

```
<!--<xsl:text>Note</xsl:text>-->
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <!--<xsl:text>: </xsl:text>-->
            </fo:inline>
            <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
```

And I have got rid of the "Note: ".

**EDIT 3:**

This didn't actually work as it created an opening block but didn't close it so I ended up removing the entire `<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/note ')]">` as we have no need for any type of notes in our system

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you have `<note outputclass="CaseSearchCourt">...` in your input XML which gets rendered as `Note: ...` and you don't want that?

Comment: Yes. I want to keep everything except the rendered Note:

Comment: This basically means that something in your XSLT renders it. Why can't you modify that part?

Comment: I couldn't find it earlier but I think I may have now. I was searching for Note: which didn't occur anywhere but I am now 90% of the way there. The : must have been added separately so that is why my grep for it failed.

Comment: I suspected such a thing. ;-) I would have looked for a template match expression with grep, though, would have made your life easier: `/template[^>]+note/`

Comment: Ok, I have it working now. Thank you Tomalak for pointing me back in the right direction.

Comment: If you want, give a quick summary of what you did in an answer of your own. You can even accept your own answer after some time.

Comment: @Hedley, you should do what Tomalak suggested, if only so that this question will stop showing up on the "unanswered questions" list.

Comment: @LarsH, I had to wait 8 hours before being able to answer the question due to my account perms. Am closing it down now.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't actually work as it created an opening block but didn't close it so I ended up removing the entire `<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/note ')]">` as we have no need for any type of notes in our system